# ViewPager inside FragmentDialog Height always equals to 0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment

I know a lot of questions just like this one have been asked, but I didn't see any real similarity to this case.

I'm using the android android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment

I'm trying show web service response in a Popup View containing swipe views, so I'm using a `DialogFragment` and inside it is a `ViewPager`, and of course there is a `ListView` inside each fragment in the `ViewPager` to show the results.

> Code:Activity that shows the Dialog

```
new ResultFragmentDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG_RESULT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
```

> ResultFragmentDialog code:

```
public class ResultFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {

private View view;
private ViewPager pager;
private FragmentsResultAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_result, container, false);
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
//Im creating the adapter here because if I don't there will be an IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment ..
            pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            adapter = new FragmentsResultAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private class FragmentsResultAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ResultListDialogFragment firstFragment;
    private ResultListDialogFragment secondFragment;

    public FragmentsResultAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        firstFragment = new ResultListDialogFragment();
        secondFragment = new ResultListDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? "First" : "Second";
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? firstFragment : secondFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
}
```

> ResultListDialogFragment code:

```
public class ResultListDialogFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;
private ListView list;
private ResultAdapter adapter;

private ResponseMultipleItems result = new ResponseMultipleItems(); 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_result_lst, container, false);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstResult);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
    adapter = new ResultAdapter(getActivity());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

public void loadResult(List<Item> result) {
    result.setResult(result);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    result.getResult().clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener {

    private Context context;

    private ResultItem item;
    private Holder holder;

    public ResultAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return result.getResult().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return result.getResult().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return result.getResult().get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        item = result.getResult().get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_result, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        if (position == result.getResult().size() - 1 && result.isHasMore()) {
            holder.txt.setText("Load more");
        } else {
            holder.txt.setText(item.getTitle());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class Holder {
        TextView txt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
}
```

> ViewPager code in layout file:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

> ListView code in layout file:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lstResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally the problem is that the created ListView inside the fragment has a height of `0`  !!!

How did I know that the lists in both fragments have the height of zero? I didn't know at the beginning, but the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` inside the `ResultAdapter` is not getting called, while the `public int getCount()` all ways gets called after the notifyDataSetChanged() is called.

So I used the HeirarchyViewer and it shows `DialogFragment` has a normal height, the  `NoSaveStateFrameLayout` for each fragment `getHeight()` attr from the heirarchyviewer shows `0`, and the `ListView` inside the `NoSaveStateFrameLayout` also have a `0` height.

The Dialog is displayed successfully and I can swipe between two invisible views !!
The background code I didn't write successfully fetches the content and passes them to the adapter, yet the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` is not triggered !!

- tried to use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` didn't work.
- tried `getLayoutParams().height = 100` after creating the listviews also didn't work.
- tried setting a new `LayoutParam` with new width and height, also didn't work.
- tried to use a `Dialog` instead of `DialogFragment` also didn't work.